# Display embedded html url video in Tkinter or Kivy

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

Is there a way to display an embedded url video  in a Tkinter of Kivy-based interface?

I saw you can display html code in Tkinter with tkhtmlview, or you can display entire web pages with cef. In addition, you can embed local video files/video streaming in Tkinter, but I found no info on embedded url video, as you would do with an HTML-based code.

My wish was to display different videos from embedded video url (not youtube videos) that are coming from an excel file and/or sql database in Tkinter or Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of embedded urls but as of a hyperlink, you can use the following code:

```py
def clickable_url():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(mylink)

Button(root, text=mylink, bd=0, command=clickable_url).pack()
```

Comment: thanks, that's a start. Is there a way to display the preview of the video in a tkinter label or similar?

Comment: Tkinter is a very old framework for GUI dev. I don't think you can embed videos in it. Although, maybe try out kivy; that may work.